# Stability of method through step size

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

When investigating the stability of a system of ODEs,$$u'=Au$$ where $A$ is diagonalisable so $$u'=R\Lambda R^{-1}u.$$ then let $y(t)=R^{-1}u(t)$ such that $$y'=\Lambda y.$$ Let $$\Lambda=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0\\0 & -5\end{bmatrix}.$$ Say we applied Euler's method to this, it results in  $y_{n+1}=(1+\lambda h)y_n$, and need $|1+\lambda h|<1$ for stability. If I wanted to find the stability in terms of $h$, then $$h \leq \frac{-2}{\lambda},$$though this results in two upper bounds for $h$ (for $\lambda=-1$, or $ -5$). For the method to be stable, I am not confident of which bound to use, so any pointers appreciated - if my working is even right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is absolutely correct. as it turns out, you will want
$$0<h< \min_{\lambda\in\sigma(A)} \frac{-2}\lambda = - \frac2{\lambda_{\max}}$$
Where $\sigma(A) = {\rm diag}(\Lambda)$ is the spectrum of $A$ and $\lambda_{\max}$ is the biggest eigenvalue. Note that from this it also follows instability if any $\lambda$ is $>0$ because then you have
$$0<h<-\frac2{\epsilon} <0$$
Which is, of course, a contradiction.

---

Also note that $h=\frac{-2}\lambda$ does not make the solution diverge, but it also removes convergence (the error is constant), which isn't exactly "stable". This is why I imposed strict inequality.

Comment: Thanks, AlexR. This is exactly what I thought, but wasn't wholly sure. I thought I must have made a mistake - I had tried with a different numerical method and system - but one of the results did not act how I expected it to. I must have made a mistake in the implementation!

Comment: Note that $\mathcal O(h)$ is very slow convergence. You'll see your results nicer if you plot the logarithm of the error.

Comment: Yes this is what I have done. The problem I had is that I had convergence for a $h>\frac {a}{\lambda}$; I must've just made a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your system is uncoupled: it is simply two unrelated ODEs that you solve using the same step size $h$. One needs $h < 2$, the other $h<2/5$. If you want **both** to be stable, then **both** conditions $h < 2$ and $h<2/5$ must hold. Which of course is equivalent to the single condition $h<2/5$.

*Aside*. In practice I would advise $h<1/5$, because the numerical solutions with $h\in (1/5,2/5)$ show oscillations, which is rather misleading.  (Even though  these solutions are stable).

In general (for matrices that are not necessarily diagonal) Euler's method is stable if **all** eigenvalues of $I+hA$ are less than $1$ in absolute value. This means that a single "bad" eigenvalue can force the use of a small $h$, even if other eigenvalues are ok.